# Xcode 6.1 getting build failed error.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

[image]i am getting this error when i want to run project in xcode 6.1. in my project there is .pch file present.

```
 clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/fffffggg/Desktop/iphone/iph/iph-Prefix.pch'
    clang: error: no input files
    Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @jace do you find solution, because i am also meet that issue, will u help me to Resolve this.?

Comment: yes i have done .setting the prefix header @Mohanraj

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean build using `cmd +shift + k` then try build the project again.

Comment: Checked the actual path to see if the file is indeed there?

Comment: file is present in my project. just i cloned from git and running it.but not able to run. can you explain  some more. and why i am getting

Answer (score 0):

So, try to remove the references of your file and add your file back again. Sometimes, it's just problem when you do copy and paste. And you probably can select the Simulator, choose the iOS Simulator from the menu. Then, choose **Reset Content and Setting**. Or, you can try to clear your derived by **Window -> Organizer -> Projects tab -> delete it**

Those are something what I will do if there are some errors that I think it should not appear. But, the message is quite clear that you are missing one file. So, you probably just go ahead with that. Sometimes, it might be just a small mistake.

Comment: i am able to see all my file is there.but dont know why this error :error: no such file or directory: '/Users/fffffggg/Desktop/iphone/iph/iph-Prefix.pch'
    clang: error: no input files

Comment: You can see it but it does not mean that XCode references it right. So, check it again? Delete and reference it again?